# Two JSONs in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two JSONs.
First is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Barsik",
        "age": 3,
        "author": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Gogo",
        "age": 56,
        "author": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Tigger",
        "age": 56,
        "author": 2
    }
]
```

And the second is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "last_name": "Ivanov",
        "first_name": "Petr"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "last_name": "Bondarev",
        "first_name": "Anton"
    }
]
```

So, how can i filter first JSON by second's id/ Now i have such code, that doesn't filter anything. Obviously, it should be some filter in second  ng-repeat, but how? It should be something like if cat.author == author.id.

```
<div ng-app="catmodelFrontendApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="author in auth track by author.id">
        <h3>Cats of {{author.first_name}} {{author.last_name}}</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="cat in cats ">{{ cat.name }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AnuglarJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) like in this [runnable demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqcpwu1y/) by filtering it by attribute `author.id`. The third parameter `true` is for comparing the exect value.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="author in auth track by author.id">
    <h3>Cats of {{author.first_name}} {{author.last_name}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="cat in cats |filter:{'author': author.id}:true"> - {{ cat.name }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AnuglarJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cats = [{
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Barsik",
            "age": 3,
            "author": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Gogo",
            "age": 56,
            "author": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Tigger",
            "age": 56,
            "author": 2
        }
    ];

    $scope.auth = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "last_name": "Ivanov",
            "first_name": "Petr"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "last_name": "Bondarev",
            "first_name": "Anton"
        }
    ];
});
```